# Nested lists and converting to floats

Tags: python, list, floating-point, nested-lists

I'm trying to read some numbers from a text file and convert them to a list of floats, but nothing I try seems to work right.

Here's my code right now:

```
python_data = open('C:\Documents and Settings\redacted\Desktop\python_lengths.txt','r')
python_lengths = []
for line in python_data:
    python_lengths.append(line.split())
python_lengths.sort()

print python_lengths
```

It returns:

```
[['12.2'], ['26'], ['34.2'], ['5.0'], ['62'], ['62'], ['62.6']]
```

(all brackets included)

But I can't convert it to a list of floats with any regular commands like:

```
python_lengths = float(python_lengths)
```

or:

```
float_lengths = [map(float, x) for x in python_lengths]
```

because it seems to be nested or something?

Answer (score 5):

That is happening because `.split()` always returns a list of items even if there was just 1 element present. If you change your `python_lengths.append(line.split())` to `python_lengths.extend(line.split())` you will get your flat list you expected.

Comment: /Thread. Thank you so much, you have no idea!! That one word has been stopping me from finishing this program for the last 4 hours -_-

Answer (score 0):

@eumiro's answer is correct, but here is something else that can help:

```
numbers = []
with open('C:\Documents and Settings\redacted\Desktop\python_lengths.txt','r') as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      numbers.extend(line.split())

numbers.sort()
print numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def floats_from_file(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            yield float(word)

with open('C:/Documents and Settings/redacted/Desktop/python_lengths.txt') as f:
    python_lengths = list(floats_from_file(f))

python_lengths.sort()

print python_lengths
```

Note that you can use forward slashes, even on Windows.  If you want to use backslashes you should use a "raw" string, to avoid problems.  What sort of problems?  Well, some characters are special with backslash; for example, `\n` represents a newline.  If you just put a path in plain quotes, and one of the directory names starts with `n`, you will get a newline there.  Solutions are to double the backslashes, use raw strings, or just use forward slashes.